# How do I create a network file download link in a webpage?

Tags: html, firefox

In a webpage, I'm trying to create a link to a file that's on a network drive, but its not working.  I'm using Firefox due to other restrictions on the website.  If I click on the link, nothing happens.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<a href="file://///D:/Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 3/File Name.xlsm">FileName</a>
```

I've also tried this, but same result:

```
<a href="file:///D:/Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 3/File Name.xlsm">FileName</a>
```

Comment: Is the website (containing the HTML document with the link in it) being accessed over HTTP?

Comment: is it that you are trying to download a file from local ? need more info..would be helpful

Comment: The file is on a local network drive, and yes, the website is http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Console, read the error messages.

When I constructed a test case, it said:

> Security Error: Content at http://localhost:7007/ may not load or link to file:///tmp/adobegc.log.

You cannot link from an HTTP served webpage to something on the user's local filesystem.

Comment: Sure enough.  No way around this?

Comment: Some browsers let you disable that security feature, but its a bad idea and I've no idea if Forfox is one of them.

Comment: No, can't do that.  I'll have to do something different then.